# How do I configure Backbone.Sync to work with request?

Tags: ajax, backbone.js, ender

When I do a Model.fetch(), I'm getting the response from request as the attributes object.

How do I override this globally in Backbone settings / request settings ?

Comment: Are you sure you want to override this? The JSON response is intended to be stored in the `attributes` object. This is what allows you to do `model.set('myProp', 'my value')` and `model.get('myProp')`

Comment: I'm getting the whole reqwest object in the attributes instead of the response text .

Comment: Not quite sure what you are asking, but sounds like you might need to override the [parse](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-parse) method in the model.